# How do I tag this specific entity? (Go to description for info)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to merge the snowball/FallingSand passenger nbt tag with FallingSand/snowball.
So, I have two commands set up:

`data merge @e[type=snowball] {Passengers:falling_block, tag:{BlockState:{Name:"minecraft:sand"}}}`

`data merge @e[type=falling_block, tag:{BlockState:{Name:"minecraft:sand"}}] {Passengers:snowball}`

The commands are supposed to detect whenever a snowball exists then make it so that a FallingSand is placed as a passenger. Then, it places snowballs on all FallingSand, and this repeats, forming a snowball/FallingSand tower. I'm not sure if it will work, since it probably will detect the non-top snowball/FallingSand and break the chain by removing all passengers then placing a FallingSand/snowball on top. Is there a way to ensure this doesn't happen?

Comment: Sorry if not clear, this is what it supposed to be:
FallingSand
snowball
FallingSand
snowball
...
FallingSand
Initial snowball

Comment: wait you can't do that? nvm just a stack of alternating between snowball and fallingsand.

Comment: If you find this comment, here is the real question. Sorry for confusion:
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/383466/how-to-tag-all-snowballs-that-arent-riding-another-entity

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tag all snowballs that aren't riding another entity?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/383466/how-to-tag-all-snowballs-that-arent-riding-another-entity)